# Different result on Google search and browser

Tags: seo, google-search, trademark

A site is using one of my clients' registered trademark to get a good rank on Google search. When I search with that keyword I find that site on top of the search result but when I check that page with my browser and read the page source the keyword is not there!

Recently we told that website admin to remove it and they told us that they've removed it. I requested support at Google to remove that page from cache but Google told us that **the cached pages could not be removed because the content, "-----------" is still active on the pages.**

I need help to start how to find this content on that page.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see the offending keyword in the page source but Google does, they might be serving different content to Google & crawlers than they are to human users & browsers.

Try loading the page with http://web-sniffer.net/ and set 'Googlebot' as the User Agent. Look through the page source you get back for any phrases that might not show through your browser. This will help you see if they're doing any dodgy (which it sounds like they already are).

Comment: Thanks for your reply but apparently on web-sniffer.net it shows the same result as normal browser does. Maybe because they use referrer as, "Referer: http://web-sniffer.net/" ?

Answer (score 0):

The keyword could be in a hidden div.   Here is a command line that I use to download a page and search it for a keyword.  In this example it is searching for the keyword `domain` on `http://example.com/`

```
curl -s -L -A 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)' 'http://example.com/' | grep 'domain'
```

You could also use your browser's view-source feature and search that.